# Is there any tool which can rearrange the css based on same type selector?

Tags: css

I've big css where selector for same things are on different place.

Is there any tool which can rearrange the css based on same type selector?

**This is just example.**

```
#main h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}
#sidebar h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#main h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}

#sidebar h4 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}


#main #box h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

**it should arranged like this**

```
#main h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}

#main h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#main #box h2 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#sidebar h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

#sidebar h4 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

if parent selector is same then all should be at same place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CSSEdit](http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/) will sort the selectors for you. **BUT**: CSS is a cascading style sheet, which means that styles inherit things from above.

If you reorder the elements in the CSS, you are effectively changing the styles - something you probably do not want to do.

Comment: then is by hand optimization is the best way for css?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - Sadly, it probably is. That is the best way to make sure you are not breaking your styles.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - Oh, well as for windows tools, I have no idea.